# Advantages of FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY when working with large memory mapped files?

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files, createfile

In my data-heavy application, I'll be working with multiple memory mapped files (mapped to files on disk) that can be up to dozens of gigabytes in size.

Will creating those files with FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY give me any benefits?

From what I gather from this documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858(v=vs.85).aspx#caching_behavior

FILE_ATTRIBUTE_TEMPORARY will tell the OS to avoid flushing to disk while it can still fit in the cache in memory.

But how big is this cache? 
Is it big enough to be useful? 
Would using the flag only be an advantage if I work with relatively small memory mapped files?

Comment: The only way to tell if it will be beneficial in your situation is to actually benchmark it. It's going to depend on your OS, the amount of installed memory, other processes on your machine, and the particular data and file I/O your app performs. There's no generic "one size fits all" answer to this question.

Comment: If a temporary file is a suitable choice then just don't bother, let the paging file backup the mmf.  Pass INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE as the 1st argument of CreateFileMapping().

Comment: Actually, the file handle is kept. We remap the file to resize it.

Comment: Do memory mapped files even use the cache? Additional research has revealed that some other flags like FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ADDESS and FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING have no effect for memory mapped files.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve here; do you even want a file in the first place?  I guess this would at least avoid bloating swap...